# whats the best way to traverse a large dictionary of words?

Tags: algorithm

lets say I'm looking for a word that may or may not be in a dictionary of 95k words - I Cannot use word length to facilitate search. My question is in regards to the fastest way to find the word without doing a O(n) look up.

Here are my two thoughts:

first, store the words in a hast table, look up of the word is O(1), this seems the best scenario in my mind, but going through different websites using Trie was also suggested, my question regarding this is whether *its practical to have a Trie that holds so many words.*
The lookup would be O(k) in this case.

So what is the most optimal way of finding a word in a large dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Optimality depends on your use case - do you care about look up-time or space? (also, do you care about inserting new words?).

The best you can do time-wise is to use a hash table, but for a dictionary, it is space-inefficient.  A trie compresses the space requirement because it stores prefixes, not the entire word, but takes longer to look up. So, to answer your question, it is more space efficient to have a trie with a large number of words than a hash table.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just searching for a single word, the cost of setting up a hash table or tree structure would exceed a linear search. These structures become (very) efficient when their costs are amortized over (very) many uses.

If the dictionary is sorted (and why wouldn't a dictionary be?), then you can look for a single word in `log(n)` time with a binary search through the file, no additional structures needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to find a word in a dictionary is a  B+ tree.And let me explain you the reason.

Lets say you have a root block of 10 strings.The strings in the block are sorted.These 10 strings are followed by a pointer to another cell of 10 strings and that goes one.So the only thing you have to do is just String compare your Key word starting by the First one until you find a word smaller in comparison (StringCompare).

If we take it as standard that each string has next to it a pointer that shows to a cell with words that are smaller in comparison,it will take you 5 steps and 5 comparisons to end to the final bracket of data that will may or may not contain your Key word.

in 5 comparisons + the comparisons in the final bracket you are searching a dictionary of 10*10*10*10*10 words.

The algorithm is of logarithmic speed      Log 100000 with base the number of strings in the cell.If each cell has 10 words you need 5 steps.

I must mention that only the Root of the tree must be stored in the Ram memory.All the other blocks can be stored in the hard drive without significant loss in performance because of the few steps.

Hope i explained right :D At least i tried! have fun

Answer (score 0):

Trie is preferable because this data-structure can be faster than hash-table. Hash tables is `O(1)` only in ideal case, in real world applications collisions can occur. Different types of trie data structure doesn't suffer from this.

Another case is compression. Trie are much more compact than hash table. Hash table require some space for efficient insert operations. If load factor of the hash table are colse to 100% than insert operations takes very long time.

With hash tables you must compare your key with at least one key from the dictionary, key comparison in this case takes `O(k)` where k in key length. With trie you are doing the same thing, your lookup operations is `O(k)`.

Tries allow ordered traversal, hash tables - don't.

There is many types of tries out there, for example ternary search trie is verty good in this particular case. Array mapped trie are also very fast, compared to regular hash table.